# Azure sharding plan for ecommerce site

Tags: azure-sql-database, sharding

I contribute to nopCommerce and I am looking to provide support for sql azure.

I understand that if you decide to use sql azure, it must be for the right reasons, mainly sharding, scalability, and high availability. I want to avoid enabled sql azure for nopCommerce if it is just going to do exactly what sql server can do.

So the next step would be to define how the sharding would happen. nopCommerce has a typical database with customers, products, categories, orders, etc. How would you design the sharding to allow for great/automatic scaling out (more dbs).

I can't seem to find a logical way to distribute the data across n-databases.

I am a beginner when it comes to sql azure, so let me know if I am barking up the wrong tree. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Azure is not just for sharding; many customers use SQL Azure without sharding. You should consider sharding only if your application scalability objectives require it. Sharding is actually complex and imposes certain limitations, regardless of the path you take. In other words, use sharding techniques with SQL Azure only if you need it.

If you are considering data federation, take a look at [my blog post](http://geekswithblogs.net/hroggero/archive/2011/07/23/preparing-for-data-federation-in-sql-azure.aspx) which provides some insights into how to prepare for it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at Federations. A couple of links I quickly Googled

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cbiyikoglu/archive/2011/01/18/sql-azure-federations-robust-connectivity-model-for-federated-data.aspx

http://vincentlauzon.wordpress.com/2011/02/05/sql-azure-federation-automating-your-database-partitioning-sharding/

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cbiyikoglu/archive/2010/10/30/building-scalable-database-solution-in-sql-azure-introducing-federation-in-sql-azure.aspx